# mongodb inbox structure multi addresses

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, mongoose, database

I'm going to create an Inbox structure in mongodb. I have some trouble on the Inbox Schema for a multi-user message.
I thought to create something like this where Recipients contains Objects. Every object contains userId and a log to know if the message was red or not.
if it's a correct(efficient!!) structure, how can the user 456 to know if he has some message to read?

```
{   
    userId: "123"
    ,recipients: [ {userId:123, read:true}
                  ,{userId:456, read:false}
                  ,{userId:789, read:false} ]
    ,text: "message wrote by user 123"
}
,{  
    userId: "456"
    ,recipients: [ {userId:123, read:false}
                  ,{userId:456, read:true}
                  ,{userId:789, read:false} ]
    ,text: "message wrote by user 456"
}
```

Comment: MORE INFO: in this example, user 123 wrote the first message and users 456 and 789 didn't read it.
after that user 456 wrote a new message to the same users (123 and 789) where users 123 and 789 didn't read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure could work provided the `CC` or `To` list (I am assuming as being represented by the `receipients` list) does not grow out of control and becomes unbound.

To answer your initial question, you can use $elemMatch:

```
db.inbox.find({receipients:{$elemMatch:{userId:456,read:false}}})
```

That should be an efficient query and will return all messages that user `456` has not yet read.

Comment: yep, recipients is the CC list. I could change it name. thanks man